# How do I check for garbage Observables in DevTools?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs, devtools

In a pursue to avoid memory leaks, how do I specifically examine an Angular app against garbage Observables (those that have not been unsubscribed from)?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is possible - such a mechanism would require a central store of all Observable - which in turn would again be a huge risk for memory leaks.

**Suggestion #1**

Try searching in your project for all uses of `.subscribe` and then check if each result contains a mechanism to unsubscribe at some point. Any manual `.subscribe` should have some mechanism of unsubscribing.

**Suggestion #2**

Use the DevTools to create memory-/heap-snapshots over time, if neither the memory nor the object-count goes up over time, while using the app, you can be fairly certain that memory leaks are not an issue for your application.
I will not go in to detail on how to use the DevTools here, because that would be "slightly" out of scope, but have a look at this link (for the Chrome DevTools): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/
(in case the link becomes unavailable at any time, just google "how to use chrome developer tools heap snapshot")

Comment: You might want to include this link along with your suggestion #1: http://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: True, that is a nice summary of different patterns to manage subscriptions, but all of them have also been already answered in questions here on SO - a quick search should help as well.